# Cannot open data from 5.x in 6.x : Mappings

Tags: elasticsearch

I've created a routine that updates ES clients from 5.x to 6.x and finally 7.x
Somehow some clients cannot be updated.
Loading existing data in 6.8 fails.
Appearently some mappings are causing this.
But there are not templates applied and I cannot see any difference to the other clients, were everything works just fine.
I know that ES has dropped `string` type and is using `text` now but where does this type `string` come from? Why doesn't it occur on the other clients then? And finally - how would I solve this? I cannot change type from `string` to `text` in 5.x and I cannot apply templates in 6.x because it's not starting up.

```
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperParsingException: Failed to parse mapping [datapoint]: No handler for type [string] declared on field [batchId]
```

UPDATE:
this is my current mapping for batchId

```
http://localhost:9200/_mapping

"batchId":{"type":"keyword"}
```

Answer (score 1):

it seems that you forgot to change the datatype from `string` to `text` in your mapping which caused `MapperParsingException` and its really good that exception is telling you that probalmatic field is `batchId`, just change it to `text` datatype and it should work.

Please refer this [elastic blog](https://www.elastic.co/blog/strings-are-dead-long-live-strings) that talks about this `string` to `text` change and provides some tips on how to handle it while upgrading.

Comment: thanks yes I just updated my question.. how can I set text datatype when es 6.x is not starting up? and how ist it possible that this problem does not occur on every client?

Comment: @yBother updated answer with elastic blog, which has some ways to handle it

Comment: okay thanks. I am still confused: 5.2 mappings show type "keyword" and not "text". and I still dont know what to do about it...

Answer (score 0):

The problem was something else:
Some clients had unexpected indices which caused the problem.
After deleting them, ES 6.x started fine.